# How can I check the clicked element has also class x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
doc.on("click", ".add_your_qora", function(e){
     // in here I need to know, has this element also "myclass" class too?
})
```

As I've commented in the code, I need to know, has `.add_your_qora` element also `myclass` or not? How can I determine that?

Comment: API documentation http://api.jquery.com/?s=class

Comment: Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+check+if+element+has+class

Comment: You've even used `.hasClass()` [in your own code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661525/how-can-i-define-the-rest-of-width)

Comment: you just can define a different function for the case: `doc.on("click", ".add_your_qora.myclass", function(e){...`. It will run for `.add_your_qora` element that has `.myclass` as well. for an opposite case you can use selector `".add_your_qora:not(.myClass)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Example without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector(".add_your_qora").addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("myclass") {
            console.log("The element has myclass");
        }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$(this).hasClass('myClass');`

Answer (score -1):

You can use className property, like

```
myFunction(){
var target = document.getElementById('the_div_id');
if(target.className === "myclass"){
    alert("it has myclass");
}
}
```

You can also have a look at this https://gist.github.com/sonnyt/8585696 , see if this helps you.